# Type coercion with Java generics

Tags: java, generics

Here I have the following code:

```
public final class Generics {
    private Generics() {}

    public static <T> T unchecked(Object obj) {
        return (T)obj; //unchecked cast warning
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //correct
        ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
        str.add("Hello");
        str.add("World");
        System.out.println(str);

        //"correct" - not type safe at all but due to type erasure this is almost legal
        ArrayList<Object> obj = Generics.<ArrayList<Object>>unchecked(str);
        obj.add(1);
        System.out.println(obj);

        //obviously wrong but still compiles (ClassCastException at runtime)
        Exception except = Generics.<Exception>unchecked(str);
        System.out.println(except);
    }
}
```

Normally a cast of the form `ArrayList<Object> obj = (ArrayList<Object>)str` would be a fatal compile error because that would violate the expectations of the use of that list. (you could insert objects that aren't strings into a string-only list)

What is the "unchecked" warning in this scenario, and how is the use of the `unchecked()` method different from casting the reference directly? How does this bypass the compiler's type checking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the "unchecked" warning in this scenario

Unchecked casts are simply casts which don't actually result in a `checkcast` instruction in the bytecode.

```
public static <T> T unchecked(Object obj) {
    return (T)obj; //unchecked cast warning
}
```

Here, it's an unchecked cast because the erasure of `T` is `Object`, so it's effectively a no-op, because `obj` is already an `Object`.

But the pernicious thing is that there *is* a checked cast inserted at the call site:

```
Exception except = Generics.<Exception>unchecked(str);
               // ^ cast here!
```

Upon erasure, the code that is effectively executed is:

```
Exception except = (Exception) Generics.unchecked(str);
```

and this fails with a `ClassCastException`. But you don't get warned about that, because the method's return type says that this will be safe, and so the compiler trusts that it is safe at the call site.

There is no way at the call site to know that the `unchecked` method is doing something dangerous. In fact, the only thing it could do which is safe would be to return `null`. But the compiler doesn't consider whether it is doing this or not: it simply takes the `unchecked` method's claim at face value.

> how is the use of the unchecked() method different from casting the reference directly?

It's not, really. The only difference is that you're implicitly casting via `Object`. So whilst this doesn't compile:

```
Exception except = (Exception) str;
```

this does:

```
Exception except = (Exception) (Object) str;
```

and would fail at compile time with the same `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 1):

> Normally a cast of the form `ArrayList<Object> obj = (ArrayList<Object>)str` would be a fatal compile error *because that would violate the expectations of the use of that list*.

That cast is a compile error because `ArrayList<String>` is not a sub-type of `ArrayList<Object>` - it is the same compilation error you get when casting a `Double` to `String`.

You can actually avoid using the `unchecked` method by using instead

```
  // ArrayList<String> to ArrayList (raw) is legal
  ArrayList<Object> obj = (ArrayList<Object>)(ArrayList) str;
  // you can also cast to an interface-
  // at runtime, str could as well extend that interface!
  // and then Runnable can be downcasted to Exception
  // obviousy wrong, but still legal
  Exception except = (Exception)(Runnable)(str);
```

Casting to an interface (`Runnable`) which is not a supertype of `ArrayList` is legal, because we could very well have a class which extend `ArrayList` and implements `Runnable`. (though it would be a strange class..)

This type of casting is a "Narrowing reference conversion", as defined in [JLS, 5.1.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.6)

Comment: It's worth mentioning a bit more clearly why you can cast to an interface even when the class doesn't implement that interface. I can't really see it in the comment :) Pull it out to plain text, rather than putting it in code.